# Getting rid of <pre> to put json in html table

Tags: php, json

I was told to get rid of the pre first and then I will be able to put the json in the html table. I searched how to remove pre tags or to unwrap json but I can't seem to find the right answer. Thanks!

```
<?php
include "lib/webdesign.php";
include "lib/lib.php";

$url = "http://10.0.0.1/lib/api/desk/";

$params = array ("action" => "list","company_key" => "1");

$result=requestURL($url,$params);

echo "Result:".$result."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: how about `strip_tags`?

Comment: Where is the `<pre>` and where is the JSON

Comment: If it is `$result` you are talking about, please show a `print_r($result);` or the result of the `echo "Result:".$result."<br/>";`

Comment: @severinolorillajr thanks! it worked. I used $json_a=json_decode(strip_tags($result),true);

Comment: Remember to accept a relative answer, (or answer it yourself and accept it) else the question will just remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = strip_tags(requestURL($url,$params));
echo ("Result {$result} <br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags()` should work just fine here.